# How to add missing zeros in a unique identifier that is missing some values using R?

Tags: r, special-characters

I have a unique id that should in total contain 13 characters, 15 with dash. It should look like this

```
2005-067-000043
```

However some entries might be like this

```
2005-067-00043 or 2005-67-000043 or 2005-067-0000043
```

I would like a script that says between first and second dash there should be three characters, if more cut zeros in front and if less add zero in front. Same goes for the last section where it says after last dash there should be six characters if less add zero in front or if more cut zero in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up the data into 3 columns, keep only 3 and 6 characters in 2nd and 3rd column and combine the columns into one again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

separate(df, x, paste0('col', 1:3), sep = '-') %>%
  mutate(col2 = sprintf('%03s', substring(col2, nchar(col2) - 2)), 
         col3 = sprintf('%06s', substring(col3, nchar(col3) - 5))) %>%
  unite(result, starts_with('col'), sep = '-')

#           result
#1 2005-067-000043
#2 2005-067-000043
#3 2005-067-000043
#4 2005-067-000043
```

```
x <- c('2005-067-000043', '2005-067-00043', '2005-67-000043', '2005-067-0000043')
df <- data.frame(x)
df

#                 x
#1  2005-067-000043
#2   2005-067-00043
#3   2005-67-000043
#4 2005-067-0000043
```

Comment: one example i did was 2021-43-0005 and i got 2021- 43-   0005. How do i make those space zeros?

Comment: It works find with`df <- data.frame(x = c('2005-067-000043', '2005-067-00043', '2005-67-000043', '2005-067-0000043', '2021-43-0005'))`. Maybe there are whitespaces in your data. Try using `trimws` to remove that. Something like `substring(trimws(col2),....` and `substring(trimws(col3),....`

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work but i just replaced those spaces with 0 using gsub.